# Somar os resultados de for x in range

Tags: python

```
k=5
for k in range (5,10):
    print(2*k**2)

50
72
98
128
162
```

Preciso somar esses resultados.

Answer (score 3):

Utilizando [compreensão de listas](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions), ficaria:

```
soma = sum(2*k**2 for k in range(5, 10))
```

Leia-se: para cada valor de `k` no intervalo `range(5, 10)` calcule `2*k**2` e some todos os resultados.

Pode ler mais sobre compreensão de listas [aqui](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/understanding-list-comprehensions-in-python-3).

Comment: muito obrigado amigo pelas listas!!

Comment: Compreensão de listas, certo? Não compressão.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode fazer assim:

```
soma = 0
for k in range (5,10):
    soma += 2 * k ** 2
    print(2 * k ** 2)

print(soma)
```

Comment: muito obrigado !!